# R Shiny App in VirtualBox Environment

Tags: r, shiny

I have a couple Shiny apps that I have been developing for several months. I am now ready to roll out my apps to the target audience, but would like to avoid the hassle of installing R on every computer, making sure it's the right version of R for all the dependencies etc.

I was told there may be a way to run a Shiny application in a Virtual environment, that I could give to the user, but I do not know much about these. Ideally, the user would simply double-click an icon and the Shiny app would open in their web browser.

I can't host the Shiny app on a server because it contains credentials to secure data, otherwise I would go that route.

Is there a way to make a Shiny application run in some kind of prepared environment that already has R and Shiny installed, as well as all the app's dependencies?

Comment: *some kind of prepared environment that already has R and Shiny installed*... Have you heard of Docker or containers or microservices? If not, what about Vagrant?

Comment: You need to do some very basic research yourself. This site is supposed to solve specific questions and problems, not teach basics.

Comment: Thank you both for your responses. Just knowing where I should start is positive momentum from where I previously was. This was helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> would like to avoid the hassle of installing R on every computer

Every computer, meaning what? Even if you handed out a VM or a Docker image, the end user still requires software installation.

The alternative is to host your application in the cloud and point people at a single URL, I think Heroku might provide R hosting.

> Ideally, the user would simply double-click an icon and the Shiny app would open in their web browser.

Again, if you're going around to "every computer" and installing software,  this requires some type of bundling into an application (which depends on external software), or if you can host on a server it's simply configuring a URL shortcut icon to open the default web browser. Are you considering  all possible operating systems for that clickable icon, though?

> Is there a way to make a Shiny application run in some kind of prepared environment that already has R and Shiny installed, as well as all the app's dependencies?

You've basically asked for a Virtual machine or Docker image.

If you want to use the VirtualBox route, I can suggest [using Vagrant to create  distributable  VM images](https://www.vagrantup.com/docs/virtualbox/boxes.html)

> I can't host the Shiny app on a server because it contains credentials to secure data,

As long as you don't allow root permissions or post that  data somewhere publicly accessible, you can very well host it on a server. Or you can host it at home and figure out how to port forward your router to the server / application

Comment: Thank you very much for your response. This is very helpful for me. I am very unfamiliar with this, but this does help point me in the right direction. I am slightly familiar with Docker, but have never used it in this way. Avoiding all software installation was never my goal, but rather avoiding the installation of R and necessary packages. For business, admin-installing R is a security risk. Especially when employees have the ability to download any R package from the web. This is why it would be ideal to have a pre-packaged environment.